# Hide columns based on input in two cells

Tags: excel, vba, date, input, hide

I'm new to VBA and trying to figure out how to make this work.

What im trying to do is to hide columns based on a FROM and a TO date input from two cells.

I got two drop-down lists with dates:

- A2 to choose date FROM and
- A5 to choose date TO ..

And from B2:NC2 I got 1 Jan - 31 Dec.

So what I'm trying to do is that if I choose:

- A2 = 5 Jan and
- A5 = 12 April,

I want all columns before 5 Jan and all columns after 12 April to hide.

This is my code so far:

```vb
Sub Hidecolumns()
Dim p As Range

For Each p In Range ("B2:NC2").Cells
       If p.Value < ("A2") or > ("A5") Then
       p.Entirecolumn.Hidden = True

End If
Next p

End Sub
```

I know my code is failing at "`if p.value < ("A2") or ("A5") >`"..
But why? And how?

/J

Comment: What specifically can't you figure out?

Comment: SO is here to help individuals who have tried to write a macro and are experiencing problems with their code. Individuals who start with "I want" usually get marked down, the question goes unanswered, and it gets `Closed`. The best way to get help is to provide the code you have tried and what is not working or the error you are experiencing. Resulting in a lot of experienced individuals on SO who will gladly provide help and guidance.

Comment: Tim Williams How to correctly make a statement to hide all columns with a date lower than the date in cell A2 and a date higher than A5

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! Don't know if this is the best solution, but this is how i did:

Sub Hidecolumntest2()
Dim cell As Range
Dim fromdate As Range
Dim  todate As Range

For Each cell in Range ("B2:NC2").Cells
For Each fromdate in Range ("A2").Cells
For Each todate In Range ("A5").Cells

If cell.Value < fromdate.Value Or cell.Value > todate.Value Then
cell.EntireColumn Hidden = True

End If
Next
Next
Next

End Sub

Hopefully someone will find this helpful sometime